# HTML/CSS Inexplicable 1px margin/border/padding

Tags: html, css, margin, padding

NOTE: The website currently does not display correctly in all browsers. This is a separate goal to that of this post. Please use safari to find and diagnose the problem.

(URL REMOVED AS SOLVED)

Is our website.

looking in safari, you will see this:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/kPCDu.png]

Looking closely at the area indicated by the arrow, you can see there is a 1px gap between the header and bottom section of our... "table" of topics.

I cannot find ANY reason that this should be there! I've used the safari web inspector and checked EVERY element, no borders, no margins, no nothing up there! It should simply not exist! And yet, it does.

So I assume that his is some kind of CSS bug/quirk and I am not sure where exactly it is originating in the HTML to even begin to google about it. Can anyone offer any help as to what is actually causing this/how to fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tables are causing your problem. You can fix it (causing some more problems) by adding this CSS:

```css
.table_list {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

But really, it's pretty useless to use tables for the section headings, although it's fine for displaying the list of forums/boards/whatever.

Comment: He'll also need to remove the negative margin bottom.

div.cat_bar { margin: 0px }